# Tagged unions with runtime defined members

Tags: rust

I'm working on a small interpreter and I'd like to represent some types on the stack with others being pointers. Here's what it would look like in C++:

```cpp
enum {
  NIL_TYPE,
  INT_TYPE,
  REF_TYPE_START,
}

union Data 
{
  int int_val;
  void *obj_val
}

struct Object
{
  size_t _type_id;
  Data _data;
}
```

`_type_id` acts as a tag for the rest of the struct. Things like integers, boolean, nils, etc, can be passed on the stack while larger things like strings and objects can be passed by reference.

The interpreter will create new types at runtime, which is what the `REF_START_TYPE` is for. When a new type is created, we'll add a value to some internal counter and that becomes the next type id and that type is expected to be a pointer.

How can I represent something like this in Rust? Enum types seem awesome, but they don't seem to allow extension. Untagged unions seem to be very much a WIP and not much help. Is there any way I can get this sort of on-stack behavior (thereby reducing a ton of allocations during math operations), while still allowing for runtime extension?

Comment: C doesn't support runtime extension of union types either, so I don't think the problem here is really rust-specific. But if it's allocation you're trying to avoid, look at e.g. https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like

```
enum Object {
    Nil,
    Int(i32),
    Runtime(TypeId, RuntimeType),
}
```

You could ensure that `RuntimeType` contains only a pointer or choose to box it immediately (`Runtime(TypeId, Box<RuntimeType>),`), but have the same end result.

If it contains a `Box`, this struct takes up 24 bytes on a 64-bit machine. Unfortunately, there's no way I'm aware of to inform the compiler that the `TypeId` and the enum's discriminant should inhabit the same location. You could instead choose to move the `TypeId` into the `Box<RuntimeType>` if your measurements show that the dereference is less bad than the extra stack size. This is all very malleable depending on what other types you embed directly into the enum. For example, a `Vec` is 3-pointers worth of stack space. If that were included, you could get away with inlining more values.

The trick becomes: what is `RuntimeType`? You haven't described the problem enough for me to guess. It could be a concrete type, or it might end up being a boxed trait object.

A slightly more complete example:

```
struct RuntimeType;
type TypeId = u64;

enum Object {
    Nil,
    Int(i32),
    Runtime(TypeId, RuntimeType),
}

impl Object {
    fn type_id(&self) -> TypeId {
        use Object::*;

        match *self {
            Nil => 0,
            Int(..) => 1,
            Runtime(id, ..) => id,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```